# Calling lightning App from a button

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, custom-button

I'm new to lightning - And I have a requirement to make a button in Opportunity which every click on it will open a page (Like a force.com site) which will get the Opportunity Data in there + Some tables.

I created the Lightning App and a quick action From "Buttons, Links, and Actions" on the Opportunity object and I want to display the App when I clicking the Button but I can't find any option about lightning App - I saw only Lightning Component.

I tried to look on the web - and I found that this is not possible - only component is available to show on an action type...

Any help with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off all Lightning app is only for testing purpose and for lightning out (you can access in visual force page or third party site.)

So you need to have a component which implements the interface to showcase in record page / home page / app page.

Comment: Thank you......